# ASP.Net table data link

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```html
public string GetMemberMessages(string ClubId, string acctno)
        {

            var data = "";
            List<Hashtable> StartList = new List<Hashtable>();
            string Conn = GetClubConnectionstring(ClubId);
            if (Conn != "Invalid Connection")
            {
                Sconn = new SqlConnection(Conn);
                string lsql ="select * from table where acctno='" + no + "' and datecompl is null order by entrydate desc";
                Getdataset(lsql, "tblnotes", ds, ref da, Sconn);

                if (ds.Tables["tblnotes"] != null && ds.Tables["tblnotes"].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["tblnotes"].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
                        for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables["tblnotes"].Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            hashtable[ds.Tables["tblnotes"].Columns[j].ToString()] = ds.Tables["tblnotes"].Rows[i][j].ToString();
                        }
                        StartList.Add(hashtable);
                    }
                    return js.Serialize(StartList);
                }
                else
                {
                    data = null;
                }
            }
            return js.Serialize(data);
        }
```

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.dataSource"> 
<table > <tr>
 <td>
 <span data-bind=" text:notes"</span>>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

I have MSSQL table, in a field i had insert my messages (ex:**Have a good day**) with external website link[Google](http://www.google.com/).
while i bind the data in my  html table like this (**have a good day www.google.com**) values are shows into  view, it working *fine*. but while i click on that external web link[Google](http://www.google.com/). it doesn't navigate google page.

I had tried in SQL server with Html  different type to link tags, what are that tag i had put into database, those tag also get visible alone with message and link.

Comment: what's the issue? in the post the is no code, sql query or error messages...

Comment: This is how i had bind my datum with table                                         <div class="widgetcontent" data-bind="foreach: $root.dataSource">
<table >
        <tr>
         <td> <span data-bind=" text:notes"</span>>
        </td>
           </tr>
  </table>
</div>

Comment: please add the details in the post; reading markup and code from the comments is a nightmare..

Comment: Sry, it's not allow to post my images

Comment: ...post the code: in your previous comment you put html markup. put the markup in the original post instead.

Comment: Yes, i did it. Please look up